# Facebook Pixel - 1st Party Cookie Option

Tags: facebook, cookies

I have a general understanding of 1st/3rd party cookies, how cookie syncs work, etc.  But not able piece together how Facebooks' new 1st Party cookie option works for their Pixel product.

What's the protocol behind the scenes that is allowing FB to establish a 1st Party relationship on a non-FB domain?

Comment: The simple fact that their JavaScript is embedded into your site, and therefor can set cookies under your domain all day long …?

Comment: https://marketingland.com/facebook-to-release-first-party-pixel-for-ads-web-analytics-from-browsers-like-safari-249478: _“When a user clicks on a Facebook-served ad, a unique string gets appended to the landing page URL. When there are pixels on the site that are opted- in to share first-party cookie data with Facebook, that URL parameter will get written into the user’s browser as a first-party cookie. The pixels then include the first-party cookie with all events it sends to Facebook.”_

Comment: @04FS - So their JS (and for that fact anyone's) is embedded outside of any sort of sandbox (iframe, etc.) then will have the capability to set 1st Party cookies.  I assume this is only due to the fact that it is JS "embedded" as other mechanisms like standard 1x1 pixels would not have that same capability.  Correct?  Regardless if directly on the page, in a container tag, and/or in an iframe.

Comment: Yes, their script code runs in the scope of your page, under your domain - so it can set cookies for that domain (on the client side, _via_ JS - via HTTP it could only set a cookie for the domain it is loaded from, and that would be 3rd-party again.)